# Extract by Attributes in Model Builder, "Table Name is Invalid"?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder

I'm attempting to use "Extract by Attributes" in model builder as part of a larger model. I'm trying to pull 6 different attributes out one by one in order to create random points within their areas. "Extract by Attributes" is the first process, and keeps returning the message "Table name is invalid". When I run it independent of the model it works fine with the same files that are plugged into the model.

Is there anything I'm missing here?

I'm running 10.2 on a Lenovo thinkpad with an I5 processor.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked (check mark) the model after specifying all input and output and seeing if all the input and output loaded accordingly by double clicking on the inputs and outputs?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the screen shot it looks like you are starting the output names with a number? Geodatabase tables are not allowed to start with a number or have spaces in them.